# Multipage PDF and graphicx's \includegraphics

Tags: beamer, graphics, includegraphics, animations

I'm working with multiple animations inside a single Beamer frame, and I wish to include only the last page of a multipage PDF page inside an `\only<n>{\includegraphics[opt]{args}}`. The problem is that those frame-separated-multipage PDFs have all different total number of pages:

I tried

```
\includegraphics[page=-1]{multipage.pdf}
```

And kinda got something going, but with a compilation error:

```
PDF inclusion: required page does not exist <16>
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Weird because the `<16>` is the last page of my `multipage.pdf` file.
If I try to compile with `page=16`, it compiles.
I thought of using `pdfpages` package, but then I don't longer have the good `\textwidth` and `\textheight` to control figure size output.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some more classic with pdflatex (only):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test with pdflatex}
\centering
\pdfximage{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}
\includegraphics[height=.8\textheight,page=\pdflastximagepages]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}\par
This PDF has  \the\pdflastximagepages\  pages
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

For R users, an alternative could be to let R the work to count the pages and pass this information to `\includegraphics`, so the LaTeX engine is irrelevant. You can test it  picking out the `latex-engine` metadata in this MWE in Rmarkdown:

[image: mwe]

````
---
latex-engine: xelatex # or lualatex, or pdflatex
output: beamer_presentation
---

```{r, include=FALSE}
library(rmarkdown)
library(knitr)
library(pdftools)
``` 

### test using `r metadata$"latex-engine"`

```{r, include=FALSE}
file <- "/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-a4-numbered.pdf" # change to some 
pages <- pdf_info(file)$pages 

```

```{r, echo=F, out.extra=paste("page=",pages,sep=""),  out.height="5cm", fig.cap=paste("This PDF has",pages,"pages")}
include_graphics(file) 
```
````

Comment: this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

With a *very* new l3kernel/l3experimental (today in texlive 2022) you can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3graphics,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\graphics_get_pagecount:nN{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}\mypagecount
\ExplSyntaxOff
\includegraphics[scale=0.5,page=\mypagecount]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way of installing it via MikTex? Or how do I manually install the .dtx or .ins files?

Comment: well there are dtx files on ctan. But you need both l3experimental and l3backend, and on the whole I would wait a few days until miktex updates too.

Comment: MikTex has the l3experimental and l3backed, but compilation via pdflatex gives me
``Undefined control sequence.
l.7 \graphics_get_pagecount:nN``

Comment: miktex hasn't the current version, it was only uploaded yesterday and miktex typically needs a few days more than texlive until it offers it. Use Fran's code until it is there, that is fine, it is what the l3-code does internally for pdflatex too.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another possibility (`pdflatex`, `lualatex`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,luatex85}
\begin{document}

\savebox{0}{\includegraphics{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}}%
\includegraphics[scale=0.5,page=\pdflastximagepages]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}

\end{document}
```